# Is the Son sealed, by the Father, 'as God' (John 6:27)?

Tags: greek, john, jesus, grammar, son-of-god

> ... τουτον γαρ ο πατηρ εσφραγισεν ο θεος. [John 6:27 TR, undisputed]

> ... this he for the father did seal the deity. [Literal]

> ... for him did the father seal *even* God. [YLT]

If one removes the italic from Robert Young's translation (the italic being an admission that the word is not in the original) then one has an equivalence :

> ... for him did the father seal God.

'Him' (the Son) is in the accusative as the one being sealed.

'the God' is nominative and therefore has equivalence to the subject 'the father'.

Instead of adding 'even' in italics, would it be appropriate to add 'as' in italics :

> ... this he, for, the father did seal *as* the deity. (Proposed)

Does the text indeed state a grammatical equivalence ?

What other reason is there for the word order to be as it is, that is to say the nominative following the verb when a nominative already precedes the verb ?

Is not the meaning that the Father has impressed his seal upon the Son to demonstrate that he is equal Deity ?

---

EDIT upon Comment :

In context, Jesus has conveyed himself away from those who would make him king based on the free distribution of food to the populace. But his ministry is far more than that. His ministry is above and beyond all that.

This is the context of Jesus revealing his sealing of the Father.

*He is more - much more - than a mere king.*

Comment: Another use of the nominative case is that it can “stand alone without a verb for emphasis” [reference](https://ugg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/case_nominative.html). YLT seems to have interpreted ο θεος in such a way, and if so, it would be more open to interpretation than  if it were acting only as a nominative in apposition.

Comment: @Nhi Thank you. Appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Op asks,

"Is not the meaning that the Father has impressed his seal upon the Son to demonstrate that he is equal Deity?"

sealed:
4972
sphragízō (from 4973 /sphragís, – properly to attest ownership, authorizing (validating) what is sealed.

4972 /sphragízō ("to seal") signifies ownership and the full security carried by the backing (full authority) of the owner. "Sealing" in the ancient world served as a "legal signature" which guaranteed the promise (contents) of what was sealed.
[ signifying "belonging to."]

I would say it is something different because of the context the verse is in along with 58 verses in John 6 that is referring to the true bread of life.

It is the one God, the Father who is putting His seal on The SON Of MAN which the Son of Man shall give to you.  This seal is upon the flesh of Jesus, and  God's approval for bread and life for the ages.  Of course when God raised Him out of the dead that was God's final stamp  or seal of approval.

> "Be not working for the food which is perishing, but for food which is remaining for eonian life, which the Son of Mankind will be giving to you, For this One God, the Father, seals." John 6:27 Concordant Literal

> Bestow your pains not on the food which perishes, but on the food that remains unto the Life of the Ages--that food which will be the Son of Man's gift to you; for on Him the Father, God, has set His seal."

It was after the people saw the miracle Jesus feeding the multitude with fish and bread bread that they sought Him out.

> In most solemn truth I tell you," replied Jesus, "that you are searching for me not because you have seen miracles, but because you ate the loaves and had a hearty meal. 27Bestow your pains not on the food which perishes, but on the food that remains unto the Life of the Ages—that food which will be the Son of Man's gift to you; for on Him the Father, God, has set His seal." 28

It was God manifesting His provision of earthly food through Jesus to the multitude to get them thinking about God, and the true bread from heaven.

Jesus was teaching a spiritual lesson from a earthly lesson.

> Our forefathers ate the manna in the Desert, as it is written, 'He gave them bread out of Heaven to eat'." 32"In most solemn truth I tell you," replied Jesus, "that Moses did not give you the bread out of Heaven, but my Father is giving you the bread—the true bread—out of Heaven. 33For God's bread is that which comes down out of Heaven and gives Life to the world." 34"Sir," they said, "always give us that bread."

> I am the bread of Life," replied Jesus; "he who comes to me shall never hunger

> Now the Jews began to find fault about Him because of His claiming to be the bread which came down out of Heaven.

> No one has ever seen the Father—except Him who is from God. He has seen the Father. 47"In most solemn truth I tell you that he who believes has the Life of the Ages. 48I am the bread of Life.

> Here is the bread that comes down out of Heaven that a man may eat it and not die. 51I am the living bread come down out of Heaven. If a man eats this bread, he shall live for ever. Moreover the bread which I will give is my flesh given for the life of the world."

> This is the bread having come down from heaven, not as the fathers ate and died. The one eating this bread will live to the age."

In light of all that was just said is to show that the seal of God was on this Son of Mankind, who later dies as a man, and through His death, burial and resurrection becomes the bread of God for the world.

> Verily, verily, I am saying to you,
> He who is believing into me has eonian life.  I am the Bread of life. ...This is the Bread which  is the descending out of heaven that  anyone may The eating of it and may not be dying.
> I am the living Bread Which descends out of Heaven.   If anyone should be eating of this Bread, He shall be living for the eon.  Now the Bread also, Which I shall be giving for the sake of the life of the world, is my flesh.  John 6: 47-51

In conclusion God  the Father was putting His seal, His ownership on Jesus , the Son  of Man and that His flesh would indeed be sealed as the true bread of heaven that God the Father Himself gives to the world and the Son of Man gives
His life for the true bread from heaven.

Comment: Up-voted +1. Thank you. Food for thought.

Comment: @Nigel J Thanks, I am grateful for your consideration.

Answer (score 3):

While I have no problem with the theology of your interpretation, there is a problem with the grammar.  The problem is that ὁ θεός is nominative and thus in apposition to the subject rather than being one of the objects of ἐσφράγισεν.  The distance of ο θεος from ο πατηρ might be used tp argue for ο θεος going with the next verse, but the context and grammar doesn't support that.  The argumentative response from Jesus' audience doesn't match Jesus claiming to ge God at this time.

> σφραγίζω 1 aor. ἐσφράγισα, mid. ἐσφραγισάμην. Pass.: pf. ptc. ἐσφραγισμένος; 1 aor. ἐσφραγίσθην (Aeschyl.+; inscr., pap., LXX, Philo, Joseph.) (provide with a) seal. 1. lit., **w. the acc. of the obj.**
> --
> Arndt, W., Gingrich, F. W., Danker, F. W., & Bauer, W. (1979). In A Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament and other early Christian literature : a translation and adaption of the fourth revised and augmented edition of Walter Bauer’s Griechisch-deutsches Worterbuch zu den Schrift en des Neuen Testaments und der ubrigen urchristlichen Literatur (p. 796). University of Chicago Press.

Comment: Then why is it after the verb and not close to that with which it is in apposition ? Up-voted +1. And what does the seal mean, if not a recognition that he is equivalent deity to the father ?

Comment: In Greek the grammar of nouns depends on case, not position.  God the Father sealed the validity of the Son's ministry.

Comment: I appreciate your comment but I have edited to bring out more of the context in realtion to your comment.

Comment: I agree with this answer. +1.  My answer supports yours.

Answer (score 3):

The OP's proposed translation is not possible because the word, God" or "deity" is NOT in either the accusative case nor the dative case to make such possible.

Indeed, the only nominative words in the final sentence of John 6:27 are: "Father", "The God" which puts them in apposition.  Thus we are compelled to translate this final sentence as something like:

> For God the Father has sealed Him [ie, the Son].

or, preserving some of the original word order more:

> For Him [the Son], God the Father has sealed

A similar sentiment is found in John 3:33 -

> The one having received His testimony has set his seal that God is
> true.

**APPENDIX - More examples of God and Father in apposition:**

In John 6:27 we have God and father in the nominative case.  Here are more examples:

- 1 Cor 8:6 - 1 Cor 8:6 - nominative case
- Rom 1:7, 1 Cor 1:3, 2 Cor 1:3 - genitive case
- Rom 15:6 - accusative case
- 1 Cor 15:24 - dative case

Comment: +1,  I agree with you.